# setup.py: data_files not doing what I expect

Tags: python, setup.py

I have added the following `data_files` section to my setup.py script:

```
data_files = [
    ('libgsync/data': [ 'libgsync/data/client.json' ]),
]
```

As expected, it copies the file to the following location, but unexpectedly omits it from the MANIFEST file:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libgsync/data/client.json
```

It also unexpectedly creates the same file here too and does include it in the manifest:

```
/usr/local/libgsync/data/client.json
```

Why?  And how do I make it produce something more predictable?

Here's the command:

```
sudo ./setup.py install --record MANIFEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using setuptools in your setup script?  If so, data files that are in your Python packages are automatically added and installed as package data, and then the explicit data_files argument also installs them.

I would remove the data_files argument; it doesn’t do what you want to do, is not portable, and generally does not work for what it’s supposed to do.

Comment: I had an issue where the data file wasn't being copied, so added data_files.  I will try again without it, but I'm pretty sure the data directory does not get copied in either case.  Will update as soon as I can test the change.